# Unity3D facebook export issues

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I have developed a mobile game at a resolution of 1242 x 2208. Now, I need to export the build for Facebook.

When I exported the build for Facebook at 360x640 resolution, the art assets become very rough and less sharp. 
In 2nd attempt I exported the build at resolution 720x1280 and then set the zoom size of the canvas div in html by half using the  zoom: 0.5 property. The results are much better but now the input was offset as the Canvas Input is based on the resolution 720 x 1280

Is there any solution to export the build for Facebook without creating low resolution art assets for so they fit and look perfect on 360x640 resolution?